# SQL Query to give me a total count of all distinct values

Tags: sql

I'm sure this is pretty straightforward but can't get my head round it at all.

In one of my DB tables, I have a column 'partitionDate'. This is populated every time a transaction is logged in to the DB table with the date 11-JAN-2023 for example. So we could have 100 transactions all with the partitionDate of 11-JAN-2023.

I've run a query to give me the total count for each distinct partitionDate

```
SELECT partitionDate, COUNT (DISTINCT partitionDate)
from tablename
```

I'm trying to get a grand total at the bottom that shows me all of the totals added up which I guess will be a SUM but I can't work it out!

Thanks

I'm trying to get a grand total at the bottom that shows me all of the totals added up which I guess will be a SUM but I can't work it out!

Comment: Please tag your DBMS, add some sample input as table and the expected result also as table.

Comment: Your query is invalid. It is lacking `GROUP BY partitionDate`. Then per partitionDate you'll count just one distinct partitionDate (namely the date itself). So, you probably want to count rows instead: `COUNT(*)`. As to the sum: this depends on the DBMS. They usually offer the `GRUPING SETS` clause and/or some form of a `ROLLUP` clause, as mentioned in gotqn's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In T-SQL:

```
SELECT partitionDate
      ,COUNT (partitionDate) 
from tablename
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS
(
    (partitionDate)
   ,()
)
```

In MySQL should be something like this:

```
SELECT partitionDate, COUNT(partitionDate)
FROM tablename
GROUP BY partitionDate WITH ROLLUP;
```

Comment: perfect thanks! That has done the trick!